# How to show alerts in Swift UIKit using MVVM, Firebase and Delegates

Tags: swift, firebase, mvvm, uikit, alert

I would like to know how can i implement a **delegate** or a **function** that helps me to ***show an alert in the ViewModel***. Basically i need to validate two text fields and when the user writes a wrong password or a wrong email it should trigger an alert. The function to trigger this alert is inside of the **ViewController** and i need to create a new class **(ViewModel)** that helps me to validate the text fields and sign to firebase

Here is my code:

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    //MARK: - @IBOutlets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

   
    //MARK: - LifeCycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setDelegates()
        startButton.isEnabled = false
    }


    //MARK: - Delegates

    func setDelegates()->Void {
        emailTextField.delegate = self
        passwordTextField.delegate = self
    }

    
    // Function that i need to trigger in the ViewModel

    fileprivate func showErrorMessage(_ errorMessage : String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "UPS!", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .default))
        
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // Function to go to the next ViewController

    fileprivate func navigateToHomeViewController() {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let homeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        homeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Function of the ViewModel all validations
    
    fileprivate func validateUserLogin(_ error: Error?, _ result: AuthDataResult?) {
        switch error {
        case .some(let error as NSError) where error.code == AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
            // validate the text field and then show the alert, i need to this, but inside the ViewModel
            self.showErrorMessage("Contraseña incorrecta")
           
        case .some(let error as NSError) where error.code == AuthErrorCode.userNotFound.rawValue:
           // validate the text field and then show the alert, i need to this, but inside the ViewModel
            self.showErrorMessage("Correo incorrecto")
           
        case .some(let error):
           // validate the text field and then show the alert, i need to this, but inside the ViewModel
            self.showErrorMessage("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.hideActivityIndicatorView()
        case .none:
            if (result?.user) != nil {
                navigateToHomeViewController()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func startButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text{
    // Function to sing in firebase, it would be inside the ViewModel
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password){(result, error) in
                self.validateUserLogin(error, result)
            }
        }
    }
    

    fileprivate func validateFields() -> Bool {
            return (passwordTextField.text!.count >= 8) && (isValidEmail(emailTextField.text ?? ""))
        }
        

        fileprivate func updateView() {
            if(validateFields()){
                startButton.isEnabled = true
                startButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            }else{
                startButton.isEnabled = false
                startButton.tintColor = UIColor.gray
            }
        }

}


func isValidEmail(_ email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

    let emailPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailPred.evaluate(with: email)
}

//MARK: - Text Field Delegate Methods

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate{
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString
            string: String) -> Bool {
            if textField == self.emailTextField {
                updateView()
            } else if textField == self.passwordTextField {
                updateView()
            }
            return true
        }
    
}
```

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osm83.png)

Comment: The issue is not clear. What more is needed to "separate the logic from the view"? Is there something in your code that's not working? Can you clarify what's being asked?

Comment: I want to create a new class where only the logic to enter firebase exists, this class would be my mvvm. The real problem is that when I try to handle the exceptions like when the password or email are incorrect I can't call the method to call the alerts from this class because it is a method of my view(ViewController) I would like to find a way to call the methods to show alerts and show my activity indicator from this new class.

Comment: this is the method I want to separate from the viewController to create my mvvm

Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password){(result, error) in
                self.displayActivityIndicatorView()
                self.validateUserLogin(error, result)
           }

Comment: and these are the methods I want to use in my mvvm (the new class)

func displayActivityIndicatorView()

func hideActivityIndicatorView()

func showErrorMessage(_ errorMessage : String)

fileprivate func validateUserLogin(_ error: Error?, _ result: AuthDataResult?)

Comment: Perhaps becoming familiar with MVVM patterns would help. In this case the UI elements will be in the View, the associated data would be (in) the Model and the ViewModel coordinates the interaction between the two. To do what you ask we would have to re-write all of your code and that would go beyond the scope of this site. Consider this: the View prompts the user to enter their credentials and when done, that is passed to the ViewModel. The ViewModel then checks with the Model to see if that data is valid - if so, that is passed back to the ViewModel, which then tells the View to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, thanks to Not Bad.

**Model**

```
import Foundation

struct User{
    
    var email : String
    var password : String
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

class AuthViewModel {
    var delegate: AuthViewModelDelegate?
    var user : User? = User(email: "", password: "")
    
    func checkCredentials(user: User) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user.email, password: user.password){(result, error) in
           switch error {
           case .some(let error as NSError) where error.code == AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:

                   self.delegate?.showError("Contraseña incorrecta")
                   self.delegate?.hideActivityIndicator()
           case .some(let error as NSError) where error.code == AuthErrorCode.userNotFound.rawValue:

                   self.delegate?.showError("Correo incorrecto")
                   self.delegate?.hideActivityIndicator()
                    
           case .some(let error):

                   self.delegate?.showError("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                   self.delegate?.hideActivityIndicator()

           case .none:
               if (result?.user) != nil {
                   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                   let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomeViewController")
                   self.delegate?.navigateToHomeViewController(homeViewController)
                   self.delegate?.hideActivityIndicator()
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

**View**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

//MARK: - @ protocols

protocol AuthViewModelDelegate {
    func showError(_ message: String)
    func hideActivityIndicator()
    func navigateToHomeViewController(_ homeViewController: UIViewController)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //MARK: - @IBOutlets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    
    //MARK: - @ Variables
    
    var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView!
    var authViewModel : AuthViewModel = AuthViewModel()
   
    //MARK: - @ Life cycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setDelegates()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    fileprivate func setupUI() {
        setActivityIndicator()
        startButton.isEnabled = false
    }
    
    func setDelegates()->Void {
        authViewModel.delegate = self
        emailTextField.delegate = self
        passwordTextField.delegate = self
    }
    
    func setActivityIndicator()->Void{
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.medium)
        activityIndicator.center = view.center
        activityIndicator.isHidden = true
        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }
    
    
    func displayActivityIndicatorView() -> () {
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.activityIndicator)
        self.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
      }
    
    @IBAction func startButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.displayActivityIndicatorView()
        guard let email = emailTextField.text else {return}
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else {return}
        
        self.authViewModel.user?.email = email
        self.authViewModel.user?.password = password
        
        self.authViewModel.checkCredentials(user: self.authViewModel.user!)
            
    }
    
    fileprivate func validateFields() -> Bool {
            return (passwordTextField.text!.count >= 8) && (isValidEmail(emailTextField.text ?? ""))
        }
        

        fileprivate func updateView() {
            if(validateFields()){
                startButton.isEnabled = true
            }else{
                startButton.isEnabled = false
            }
        }

}


func isValidEmail(_ email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

    let emailPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailPred.evaluate(with: email)
}

//MARK: - Text Field Delegate Methods

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate{
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString
            string: String) -> Bool {
            if textField == self.emailTextField {
                updateView()
            } else if textField == self.passwordTextField {
                updateView()
            }
            return true
        }
    
}

//MARK: - @ AuthViewModel Delegate Methods

extension ViewController : AuthViewModelDelegate{
    func hideActivityIndicator() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if !self.activityIndicator.isHidden{
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                   self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                   self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true

               }
           }
        }
    }
    
    func navigateToHomeViewController(_ homeViewController: UIViewController) {
        (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.changeRootViewController(homeViewController)
    }
    
    func showError(_ message: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "UPS!", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .default))
            
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```